# Action on Google Trivia in italian language

Tags: action, google-home

I create a quiz with template Trivia. I created the English and French version. But if I add Italian I do not see in the Action section the possibility of choosing Italian. How you do it?

thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mDrK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not all languages are supported for all templates. Italian is a relatively recent update, so they may not have finished the internationalization support for this yet.